# Let Finder display files with a user-defined extension

Tags: finder

I have defined myself a file extension `.ev`, they are actually text files, which can be opened by `TextEdit`.

In `Finder`, by `Column` view, a `.txt` document can be displayed directly on the right hand side. Does anyone know if it is possible to let Finder show `.ev` as well, it will be more handy:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Make OS X's Quick Look work for custom file extensions](http://superuser.com/questions/230204/make-os-xs-quick-look-work-for-custom-file-extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest [QLStephen.qlgenerator](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/releases/download/1.4.3/QLStephen.qlgenerator.1.4.3.zip) (direct download!) from the [QuicklookStephen GitHub project](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen). Unzip the file and move it either to /Library/Quicklook or ~/Library/Quicklook.

Now you should get a file preview either in Finder column view or by choosing the file and hitting the <kbd>space</kbd> bar.

Comment: The link in the answer is a direct download. Here's the project link: https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/

Comment: @tubedogg This was intended but I added a link for the github page, thanx...